# Can we add dbt test in post hook in config?

Tags: dbt

my ask is something like this:

{{ config({ "materialized":'table',
"post_hook":["dbt test -s model_name",
"insert into {{ source('tgt_schema','tgt_table') }}  select * from {{source('source_schema','source_tbl') }}"
]}) }}

I want to test model before inserting data into target table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this won't work the way you want it to:

1. Post hooks are executed by your database, not on your command line. So the `dbt test -s model_name` will fail, since your database doesn't know what that means
2. You have to manually manage transactions in hooks; most likely your insert statement will not be committed and will instead be rolled back

Thinking about ddl like `insert` is typically a dbt antipattern. For a typical dbt model materialized as a table, dbt wraps your select statement in a `create table as (...)` statement, which effectively "inserts" the data into a new table. The typical dbt workflow would build this new table, and then test the new table -- before you've built the table there isn't really anything to test.

I think what you probably want is something closer to a [blue-green deployment](https://discourse.getdbt.com/t/performing-a-blue-green-deploy-of-your-dbt-project-on-snowflake/1349), where you build your production tables in a new location (schema or database), test that deployment, and if the tests are successful, you swap in the newly-built tables for the old ones. This is a great pattern, although much more complex than a vanilla dbt deployment.

If you really want to test a query before materializing it, you can break that up into two models, and use the `ephemeral` materialization on the first one. You can then test the first model before building the downstream one. (Note that this may be terrible from a performance standpoint, but ymmv).

So, for example, in `model_one.sql`

```sql
{{ config(materialized='ephemeral') }}
select my, complex, logic
from {{ ref('my_upstream_table') }}
```

Then you'd add tests in `model_one.yml`:

```yaml
version: 2
models:
  - name: model_one
    columns:
      - name: my
        tests:
          - not_null
          ...
```

Then in `model_two.sql`

```sql
{{ config(materialized='table') }}
select * from {{ ref('model_one') }}
```

Then at the command line,

```bash
$ dbt build
```

Will first run all of the tests against `model_one` and then materialize it as a table by building `model_two`.

This would also work fine if `model_two` were an `incremental` model, if you wanted to select a subset of your data using `model_one`. But if you did that, you would lose the ability to use the `is_incremental()` macro, and `--full-refresh` would not work. In that case, I would probably hardcode the filter in `model_one` and then repeat all of that logic again in `model_two`

`model_one.sql`:

```sql
{{ config(materialized='ephemeral') }}
select my, complex, logic
from {{ ref('my_upstream_table') }}
where my_timestamp > getdate() - interval '1 day'
```

Then in `model_two.sql`

```sql
-- we're no longer selecting from model_one,
-- so put a ref in a comment to make dbt think
-- it is downstream, so it only builds after
-- the tests run on model_one
-- {{ ref('model_one') }}

{{ config(materialized='incremental') }}
select my, complex, logic
from {{ ref('my_upstream_table') }}
{% if is_incremental() %}
where my_timestamp >= (select max(my_timestamp) from {{ this }})
{% endif %}
```